# Manipulate images with Python for image quiz (big pixels areas)

Tags: python, image

I want to manipulate some images with Python for a little quiz game. The quiz player should guess the image.

I think an image with only big pixel areas would be fine. I want a similar result like this: https://www.ixxiyourworld.com/media/2387631/ixsp110-van-gogh-petrol-pixel-03.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try PIL to first downscale the image massively to a given kernel size, then upscale with NEAREST back to the same size -

```
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

img = Image.open("van_gogh.jpg", mode='r')

factor = 100

kernel = (img.height//factor, img.width//factor)
pixelated = img.resize(kernel,resample=Image.BICUBIC) #downsample
pixelated = pixelated.resize(img.size,Image.NEAREST) #upsample

#Grids
grid_color = [255,255,255]

dx, dy = factor, factor
g = np.asarray(pixelated).copy()

g[:,::dy,:] = grid_color
g[::dx,:,:] = grid_color

pixelated2 = Image.fromarray(g)
pixelated2
```

[image]

Increasing the factor here, will pixelate the image further.

```
factor = 100
```

[image]